# Rails before_save is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, before-save

I want to calculate @rating of each item before creating/updating.
here is my model:

```
class SmsController < ApplicationController
  before_save :calculate_rating
  def new
  end

  def create
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    def calculate_rating
        self.rating=self.happy-self.sad+(3*self.report)
    end
end
```

but when I add some random seeds to the DB the rating attribute for all of them is nil.
Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A before_save callback is part of the ActiveRecord module (for models) in Rails. 
[ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

So, your before_save directive and method would go in the Sms model versus the SmsController

Comment: Thanks! My first rails app... :)

Comment: Anytime ... and have fun :)! Rails is awesome